# Site Action Menu not coming up after Moss 20007 upgraded to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

We have migrated the Moss 2007 Project to SharePoint 2010 with out visual-upgrade.The site action option is not coming up .As in the picture you can see it is behind the landing page of the content.Can any one help me how can I overcome form this issue

[image]

Comment: did you try to enable the compatibility mode in IE and try it

Answer (score 1):

Please switch from custom .master page to default one, and test if it works then. Looks like your custom master page has some MOSS specific styles and even JavaScript that is not compatible with SP2010.

Start from default master page and copy custom styles/JavaScript and other customizations one by one to determine which one is breaking the functionality. Finally after you've figured out the one (usually) critical thing causing the issue, you can switch back to your custom master, modify it there, and finalize the job.

Comment: Hi Palo, Site looks perfect in chrome and firefox except IE.Is there any settings to change in IE

Comment: What IE version is that? IE6 is not supported, for others it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Hi Palo .The IE version is 9